# How to hide Yosemite "search tip" on spotlight search?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I just upgraded to Yosemite for OS X and now whenever I use Spotlight Search there's this giant message in the middle of my screen (beneath the search bar) that starts off "In addition to searching your Mac, Spotlight now shows suggestions from the Internet, iTunes, the App Store, etc etc etc etc."

How can I get rid of this? I have used it many times but it continues to show this information as if it were the first time I had used it since installing Yosemite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's supposed to disappear after you use Spotlight three times, but you can force it to disappear by setting the use count to three and setting `showedFTE` to true:

```
defaults write com.apple.Spotlight showedFTE -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Spotlight useCount -int 3
killall -HUP Spotlight
```

Comment: Amazing, worked perfectly. Too soon to accept the answer. How the hell did you know this? Are you an Apple OS dev?

Comment: @Aerovistae When I set up new users on a network, these are the kind of preferences I pre-set—I have kept a list of all sorts of preferences like this. For finding out things like this in the first place, I make a new user, read the relevant preferences for an app with `defaults read`, do things, then read again and make note of the preferences that change. Considerably less amazing than being an OS X developer!